# jvi indent by tabs configuration

Tags: netbeans, jvi

I'm using netbeans+jvi. I'm required to use tabs for indentation. however i'm not sure how i should configure jvi such that commands like >> (normal mode) use tabs. right now they use spaces. I want to know how I can configure it to use tabs instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jVi supports much of vi/vim tab handling features/options

In NB, bring up the jVi options: Menu>Tools>Options>jViConfig
Under the "BufferModification" tab there is the

```
'expandtab' 'et'
```

option. You want this false (not checked). That should be all you need to change to get going.

There is also the

```
'softtabstop' 'sts'
```

option which you may find useful.

The option

```
'tabstop' 'ts'
```

should almost *always* be 8, otherwise there's usually trouble.

You can refer to [online jVi docs](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/?vimhelp/help.txt.html) or even the vim help in your local/native vim editor.